# add statistics of dataframe in new columns

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics

I have a dataframe df like this:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F   ....   Z
0  3  4  7  1  5  10  ....   2
1  2  5  8  3  3  18  ....   3
2  5  4  9  5  6  75  ....   2
3  1  5  4  7  9  7   ....   1
4  4  5  2  1  2  10  ....   1
5  7  4  3  0  4  10  ....   0
```

and i added a new column with a statistic for the column F like this:

```
df['F_mean'] = df['F'].mean()
df['F_std'] = df['F'].std()
df['F_min'] = df['F'].min()
df['F_max'] = df['F'].max()
```

is there any way to add this statistics mean,std,min,max for all columns in a way that i don't have to type every new column with hand? I tried with this code for the mean function but i get an error code 'Index' object has no attribute 'mean'.

```
df[columns + '_mean'] = df.columns.mean()
```

my goal is to add columns like this to my df Dataframe, but for every column A till Z

```
  A_mean   A_min   A_max ....Z_max
0  1        4        7  
1  1        4        7  
2  1        4        7  
3  1        4        7  
4  1        4        7  
5  1        4        7
```

Thank you,
R

Answer (score 3):

You can look for `DataFrame` with `describe()`.

```
df.describe()
```

This function gives you several useful things all at the same time. For example, you will get the three quartiles, mean, count, minimum and maximum values and the standard deviation. This is very useful, especially in exploratory data analysis.

Just an example:

```
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3
0     1    50     3
1     1    40     3
2     1    11     3
3     2    10     4
4     2    25     4
>>> df.describe()
           col1       col2      col3
count  5.000000   5.000000  5.000000
mean   1.400000  27.200000  3.400000
std    0.547723  17.655028  0.547723
min    1.000000  10.000000  3.000000
25%    1.000000  11.000000  3.000000
50%    1.000000  25.000000  3.000000
75%    2.000000  40.000000  4.000000
max    2.000000  50.000000  4.000000
```

I do not see the take them all into one go as a column but you can define rather.

## column standard deviation  of the dataframe

```
df.std(axis=0)
```

## Row standard deviation of the dataframe

```
df.std(axis=1)
```

So, not being specific to row or column you can somewhat try like below for all .

```
df['F_mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
df['F_std'] = df.std(axis=1)
df['F_min'] = df.min(axis=1)
df['F_max'] = df.max(axis=1)
```

Better :

```
>>> df.describe().loc[['count','mean', 'std', 'min', 'max']]
           col1       col2      col3
count  5.000000   5.000000  5.000000
mean   1.400000  27.200000  3.400000
std    0.547723  17.655028  0.547723
min    1.000000  10.000000  3.000000
max    2.000000  50.000000  4.000000
```

Comment: yes but how do i get this count, mean,std, min,max in a new column like i asked for df.F for example?

Comment: @raffa_sa, just updated the answer see if that helps.

Comment: i understand what you mean but than i will have to write for every column an extra code `df['A_mean'] = ` , `df['A_std']= `  ,  `df['A_min']= ` ,  `df['A_max']= ` and then the same for B,C,D,E,F till Z. My question is how can i do this easier so that i don't have to write it for every column per hand?

Comment: try .. >>> `df.describe().loc[['count','mean', 'std', 'min', 'max']]`

Comment: i updated my goal @pygo

Comment: I'll check on this, let's see if I can have something on this.

Comment: let me know if you know it @pygo

Comment: Sure thing @raffa_sa

Comment: @pygo - I think iit looks nice, no problem with answer.

Comment: But OP needs min, max ,std  in a separate column like he mentioned in question at the bottom,  suppose he has 5 columns col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 then he need it for each column like col1_min, col1_max, col1_std  like that way :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `.describe()` and select the rows you actually need.